# magento 2 : Call on click function custom module template file

Tags: magento2, template

I want to call on click function in template file with script type "text/x-magento-init".

Then please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code in js file:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) { 
        console.log(config);
        $(document).on("click","input[id^='your-button-id-here']", function () {
             console.log('click');
        });   
    };
});
```

Add below code in template file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
   "*": {
     "Your component name here": {"url":"value"}
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I already used this but this is not standard coding.I want to use script type text/x-magento-init

Comment: How can i get component value in js file?

Comment: use `$(this).val();` code

Comment: Actually i want to pass url from template file and want to get url in js file then how can i get?

Comment: @SnehaPanchal updated answer please check it

Comment: don't get anything

Answer (score 3):

.js file add this function

```
      myfunction: function () {
                $('#your_id').click(function () {
                   //your code goes here
                });
            },`
```

Your template data-bind should be:

```
 <input type="text"
                           id="your_field_id"
                           name="name"
                           data-validate="{required:true}"
                           data-bind='
                            attr: {title: $t("title")},
                            value: fieldvalue,

                            event: { "input": myfunction}'
                           class="input-text"/>
```

Comment: This function not call.I want to add function while click on button

Comment: then use the event attribute in submit button.

Comment: <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: myfunction,
                        attr: {title: $t('title')},
                        
                       )}
                        "
                        data-role="review-save">
                    
                </button>